# Custom List buttons Supported in Salesforce1?

Tags: salesforce1-app, custom-button, related-list

Custom List buttons(**buttons on the related list**) not showing up in Ipad(Salesforce 1 app).

I see there is a [knowledge article](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000187793&language=en_US) from salesforce which says

> Custom Buttons are only supported in Salesforce1 if their "Content
>   Source" is Visualforce and they are "Detail Page Buttons"
>
> The Visualforce page must also have the "Available for Salesforce
>   Mobile Apps" checkbox checked.

Are Custom list buttons Supported with the Salesforce1 App?

Answer (score 1):

The closes equivalent of a related list button in Salesforce1 that I've seen would be either:

1. A [publisher action](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=actions_overview.htm&language=en_US) on the object itself
2. A custom page you embed as a [mobile card](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2013/12/extend-your-salesforce1-app-with-mobile-cards.html) which will show up in the related lists area

Without knowing more details about what your buttons are doing, I can't really be more specific about which to use.

The main thing to remember is that Salesforce1 on the mobile device is a totally different use case from the full browser, and often times the custom button doesn't even make sense for a mobile scenario. Make sure you really evaluate if the action the custom button gives your users is applicable on a mobile device, or if it's something the user should be going to the full site for.

If you're still confused this may help: [Salesforce1 Admin Cheatsheet](http://res.cloudinary.com/hy4kyit2a/image/upload/s1_admin_cheatsheet_cheatsheet.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Yes custom List buttons are supported in Salesforce1 for List Views. However QuickAction are not supported in Salesforce1(List View only).

All you have to do is create a Custom button and can embed the visualforce page as defined in the steps below as:

Steps:
1. From Setup, click Object Manager, then click Lead.
2. Click Buttons, Links, and Actions, then New Button or Link.
3. Name the button.
4. Select List Button.
5. Content Source: Visualforce
6. Select your visualforce page. The visualforce page should use the object's standard controller.
SAMPLE VF CODE:

```
  <apex:pageBlock title="Edit Stage and Close Date" mode="edit">

     <apex:pageMessages />

     <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!leads}" var="opp">

        <apex:column value="{!opp.Name}"/>

        <apex:column headerValue="Email">

           <apex:inputField value="{!opp.Email}"/>

        </apex:column>

        <apex:column headerValue="Phone">

           <apex:inputField value="{!opp.Phone}"/>

        </apex:column>

     </apex:pageBlockTable>

  </apex:pageBlock>
```

7. Add button to the layout:
   Stay in the Lead object, click Search Layouts for Salesforce classic menu, then select Edit under ListView.

   > > Add your button to the "Selected Buttons".
   > >     Save.

Hope this helps.

Thanks,
Mohammad Anis